# Assign/Remove Buyer Group using apex in B2B Lightning Commerce?

Tags: apex, lightning, b2b-commerce

Could you please someone explain the relationship between Buyer Group and account ?

I am trying to assign/remove a Buyer group to an account, but not able to assign using Apex.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using BuyerGroupMember object which has reference to Buyer Group and Buyer Account.

If you want to assign a BuyerGroup to a Buyer Account then you can use below code to assign BuyerGroup.

```
        BuyerGroupMember bm = new BuyerGroupMember();
        bm.buyerId = accountId;
        bm.BuyerGroupId = buyergoupId;
        insert bm;
```